# Does npm cache packages?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

In my server, npm doesn't cache any package and cache directory is empty.

```
#www@iZ2zefuufnen6rfx7c81u7Z:~/.npm$ nvm current
v9.4.0
# www@iZ2zefuufnen6rfx7c81u7Z:~/.npm$ npm config get cache
/home/www/.npm
# www@iZ2zefuufnen6rfx7c81u7Z:~/.npm$ ls
anonymous-cli-metrics.json  _cacache  _locks
```

My npm config

```
www@iZ2zefuufnen6rfx7c81u7Z:~/.npm$ npm config ls
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/5.6.0 node/v9.4.0 linux x64"

; node bin location = /home/www/.nvm/versions/node/v9.4.0/bin/node
; cwd = /home/www/.npm
; HOME = /home/www
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

=====**update**

I found that after node@5.0 npm stores cache data in an opaque directory within the configured cache, named _cacache.https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache

```
www@iZ2zefuufnen6rfx7c81u7Z:~/.npm$ du -h --max-depth=1
56M ./_cacache
4.0K    ./_locks
8.0K    ./node-sass
56M .
```

The _cacache directory is just 56MB

```
www@iZ2zefuufnen6rfx7c81u7Z:~/.npm$ npm cache verify
Cache verified and compressed (~/.npm/_cacache):
Content verified: 1164 (39196729 bytes)
Index entries: 1167
Finished in 1.321s
```

====**update**

Another test in my project.
After run `rm -rf node_modules && npm clean cache --force` , then run `npm install` added 1551 packages in 171.389s. And then `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` added 1551 packages in 152.378s. Does npm really use cache?

Answer (score 11):

Global package cache is used by default. You should notice a difference in your install timings if you first do an "npm cache clean". That will clean up anything not installed globally, for those you will have to explicitly do an "npm uninstall"

Comment: after run `rm -rf node_modules && npm clean cache --force` , then run `npm install `  added 1551 packages in 171.389s. And then `rm -rf node_modules && npm install `  added 1551 packages in 152.378s. Does npm real use cache?

Comment: please verify that "npm cache clean --force" is actually clearing your global cache. In windows, c:/users/username/AppData/Roaming/npm

Comment: I didn't understand what was meant by **do an `npm cache clean`. That will clean up anything not installed globally, for those you will have to explicitly do an "npm uninstall"**, but I ran checked the size of the `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache` folder befor running `npm cache clean --force` and after running it and see that it definitely removed a lot of data (cache).  I know think the answer should say, **for those you will have to explicitly do an `npm -g uninstall`**

Comment: That’s a fair point. Cache clean will not uninstall Globally or other installed packages. What it will do is remove cached packages from the global cache located in the above mentioned roaming folder in the Windows environment